# Convert png sequence to x264 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, png, x264

I am trying to convert a series of pngs into an mp4 video. I am using ffmpeg, and want to encode the video with the H.264 codec. Using the command

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -b 1800k -i _tmp%04d.png -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

I get the following warning message

```
Incompatible pixel format 'bgra' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
```

My understanding is that there is an alpha channel in the pngs, which the x264 encoder cannot handle. Is there a way to get around this problem? Is there, for example, a way to get the encoder to ignore the alpha channel (my pngs don't actually have any transparent elements)?

I'm aware that I could batch convert the pngs beforehand to strip the alpha channel, but the sequence of images is produced by another program, and having to preprocess the images each time I make a video would be less than optimal.

Edit: After stripping the alpha channel from each frame using the command

```
convert in.png -background white -flatten +matte out.png
```

ffmpeg gives the warning message

```
Incompatible pixel format 'pal8' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
```

so still no dice.

Comment: The `Incompatible pixel format` is just a warning, not an error. Does your output actually work, or are there artifacts? Also, please include the full, uncut command line output from FFmpeg dor debugging purposes. // @Louis The OP wants x264, not H.264.

Comment: @slhck but x264 is a program not a codec.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of using [AVISynth](http://avisynth.org/) and [frame serving](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/FAQ_frameserving) to get around the problem, but it looks like ffmpeg now has native support for AVISynth. Meaning you can use AVISynth scripts as input.

So with a script, **sequence.avs**, you could do:
`ffmpeg -i sequence.avs -vcodec libx264 out.mp4`

Where **sequence.avs** is:
`ImageSource("_tmp%04d.png", start=0, end=1, fps=30).ConvertToYV12()`

Note: The optional start and end parameters reflect that I tested with two images, `_tmp0000.png` and `_tmp0001.png`.

See also: More [color formats](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Convert). The [ImageSource](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/ImageSource) documentation.